# Reset fetch in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i got a little problem with my code. I need to reset my fetch but i can't find a way to do it. Thanks in advance and sorry if i have make some error, English is not my first language.

Here is my code :

```
while($donnees=$req->fetch()){

    echo 'compare :' . $donnees[0] . '</br>';

    while($donnees2=$req2->fetch()){

        echo $donnees2[0];

        if($donnees[0]==$donnees2[0]){
            echo '/ ok /' . '</br>';
        }
        else {
            echo '/ not ok /'  . '</br>';
        }
    }
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gexu.png)

Comment: By "resest" you mean you want to go back to the first row? To be honest you might be better to do fetchAll on $req2 outside the loop and put it into an array, which you can then loop as many times as you like.

Comment: where exactly you want to reset/break your fetch? what is the desired result?

Comment: Show us your proper code. Only seeing while, we can't tell you anything.

Comment: Thank for tou help, I resolve my problem.

Comment: while ($don=$req->fetch()){
    echo ' la salle : ' . $don[0] .'</br>';
    $req2=$bdd->query("SELECT classLib FROM `classroom`");

    while($don2=$req2->fetch()){
        echo ' est comparer a :' . $don2[0] . ' il est :';
        if($don[0]==$don2[0]){
            echo 'compatible' . '</br>';
        }
        else{
            echo 'aucune classe trouver dans la bdd' . '</br>';;
        }

    }

}